# Name of metric space with a function defined over it

Tags: functions, metric-spaces, terminology

**Preliminaries:** A metric space is a set (in my case I have multiple of these sets $o_i$) with a given metric (in my case $m$) defined on its elements, so in my case I have the metric spaces $s_i=(o_i, m)$. I am also given a family of function $w_i: o_i \rightarrow \mathbb R$, each with the respective $o_i$ defined as its domain.

**Question 1:** Now I would like to define the family of tuples $(s_i, w_i)$ or $(o_i, m, w_i)$. Is there a mathematical name for $(s_i, w_i)$ or $(o_i, m, w_i)$?

**Question 2:** Since, for my context, the $m$ is not too important, I would also be happy for a term of $(o_i, w_i)$. I know that I could just say it is a "function and its domain", but in my case the sets / the domains are the most important objects of consideration. The functions are just weighting functions over the elements of each respective set. That is why I am looking for name that includes both and possibly puts emphasis on the set.

**Afterthought:** Since $m$ is the same metric for each set, the union of all o_i is a metric space as well.

Comment: It sounds a little bit like an [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology)) for a dimension-$1$ manifold.  However you haven't said that the $w_i$ are homeomorphisms, or any other restriction.

Comment: @JairTaylor: Very interesting idea, I never looked into atlases before... let's break it down: the weight function would be continuous, but a homeomorphisms is required to be bijective and the weight function does not have have to be that. Also, an atlas seems to be of a manifold, while I am talking about a metric space. I am not sure, but I think a metric space is not always a manifold, right?

Comment: I think you get the idea that each $o_i$ is a "chart" right? I think the entire manifold needs to be covered by (at least?) one chart, while my metric space does not need to be covered by the $o_i$ and the weight function is no transition function of any sort.

Comment: Or maybe I get you wrong and you mean that $o_i$ is the manifold (for the atlas) and the weight function is the transition function to $\mathbb R$ which is the chart? In my case $o_i$ are metric spaces *and* manifolds... But I would not know how to cut $o_i$ into parts such that for each part the weight function would be bijective... Any more thoughts?